# Kendo DateTimePicker changes format after submitting

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, date, kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

I have kendo datetimepicker in kendo grid popup editor.
I describe field in model with format:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

And in EditorTemplate

```
@Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.Date).Value(DateTime.Now).Format("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
```

I also have DateTimeBinder

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var displayFormat = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString;
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);            

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayFormat) && value != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.AttemptedValue))
        {
            DateTime date;
            displayFormat = displayFormat.Replace("{0:", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty);

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value.AttemptedValue, displayFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            {
                return date;
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, string.Format("{0} Incorrect Format", value.AttemptedValue));
            }
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
```

problem is when I save this popup and reaches the model in the controller server side it is with format dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss not dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss. for example, if I save with this time 31.03.2015 08:56, after submitting in server, it becomes 31.03.2015 8:56. Have you had case like this??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach below that is working without any problem.

**Model:**

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Start Date")]
public DateTime? StartDate{ get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate)
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.StartDate)
    .Animation(true)
    .Culture("tr-TR") //Set culture
    .Footer(false)
    .Format("dd.MM.yyyy")
    .Min(new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)) //Set min date of the datepicker
    .Max(new DateTime(2099, 12, 31)) //Set min date of the datepicker
    //.Value(DateTime.Today) //Set the value of the datepicker
    //.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-datepicker" })
)
```

I think you do not need `DateTimeBinder`